# Amazon web instance unresponsive

Tags: amazon-ec2, amazon-web-services

My Amazon web instance (EC2) is suddenly unresponsive. I can't ssh in, and I can't properly load the website via my web browser; only basic text and broken image links appear. The only change I know of is that I recently updated my public IP for the website. I'm quite new to AWS; any idea why my instance might be unresponsive? Is it possible to check its "health" somewhere? (I can see CloudWatch metrics from the web console, but it is not providing any useful information.)

Update: [This appears to be problem others encounter](https://forums.aws.amazon.com/message.jspa?messageID=384138) as well, but I haven't found any resolution as of yet.

Comment: did you set your dns name within your web server (apache/nginx or whatever)? are you using an ssl certificate? you can have some information through cloudwatch metrics, or get the machine system log by clicking right on your "instance > instance settings > get system log" from the UI. However, if you want advanced monitoring, you will have to use an external tool (there are a lot of tools available, such as nagios, zabbix, newrelic, dynatrace etc). you can also install the aws cloudwatch agent on your machine to get your own logs and metrics

Comment: I didn't set the DNS name, no. I am not using an SSL certificate.

Comment: mmh... and what instance type are you using, with what running on it?

Comment: ubuntu-trusty-14.04-amd64-server-20150325 , with an Elgg website running.

Comment: what size is your instance? if this is a free tier instance, then this may be worth to try with a bigger instance. I don't know Elgg very well, but it may be too much for this kind of instance. Free tier instances are good for various tests, but not very strong. Are you sure that the IP change was the real cause? to be honest, I see no real reason for an instance to become slow when changing IP, if you have nothing related to IP or DNS within your applicative configuration :/

Comment: As far as I know there's nothing IP-dependent, but Elgg might be built that way; too bad it's not obvious if it is or not. There's hardly any usage on the site and Elgg seems quite lightweight, so I doubt the free tier limitations is it. The slowdown correlates extremely strongly with the IP address change, so that makes me suspect it very strongly, especially because others encountered the problem, too.

Comment: I have had a micro instance in the past, with mysql + apache + solr (but very small usage of solr) running. The vm was crashing from time to time. I reduced the number of child processes launched by apache and it  worked properly then. As a test, you can easily change your instance size by right-clicking the instance > instance settings > change instance type (your instance has to be stopped to do so). You can try with a bigger one, test if it works and eventually come back to micro instance if you wish

Comment: That's a great idea -- thank you! I'll give it a shot!

Comment: AGH. Wow. Ok. That's entirely my fault. Looks like Elgg has an internal database entry that requires the website's URL, which it sets during installation. I just needed to change it. Thanks for your help, @Tom.

Comment: glad you found it :)

Answer (score 0):

After I regained the ability to ssh into my web instance, which occurred spontaneously after some time, I discovered that my Elgg installation was the problem. Specifically, it was using the old IP address of my web instance; [I simply needed to provide the new one.](http://learn.elgg.org/en/stable/admin/duplicate-installation.html#change-the-site-url) A very specific problem, I know, but hopefully it helps someone else!